# Java 7 PathMatcher: Does ** match 0 directories?

Tags: java, path

Have a look at the following example:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] pArgs) throws Exception {
        final PathMatcher pm = FileSystems.getDefault().getPathMatcher("glob:**/*.java");
        final Path p = Paths.get("Test.java");
        System.out.println("Match = " + pm.matches(p));
    }
}
```

I'd expect the output to be `"Match = true"`, but in fact the output is `"Match = false"`.

In other words: Does the pattern `**` match 0 directories, which I would expect? Or does it match one, or more directories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [`getPathMatcher`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html#getPathMatcher-java.lang.String-) documentation:

> The following rules are used to interpret glob patterns:
>
> - The `**` characters matches zero or more characters crossing directory boundaries.

This means that `**/*.java` will match, for example, `/Test.java` or `some/directory/Test.java`. But the leading slash will still be present in the matched pattern, meaning it won't match `Test.java`.

You shouldn't regard `**` as 0 or more directories, but as 0 or more characters crossing directory boundaries.

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to @Tunaki answer, you can use alternatives by using `{}` and sub pattern separated by `,`. It does not accept alternatives (eg: you can't do `{a,b{0,1},c}`).

To make your code work, use the pattern `glob:{,**/}*.java` instead of `"glob:**/*.java"` as you expected.

It will:

- either matches `*.java` (like `Paths.get("Test.java")`)
- either matches `**/*.java` (like `Paths.get("src/main/java/Test.java")`)

If you want more details about glob implementation, you can find it in the [JDK sources](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u60/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/sun/nio/fs/Globs.java).

To summarize it, they are simply translated into a "simple" [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html):  `{,**/}*.java` translate to `^(|\*\*\\}.*\.java$` on Windows, `^(|\*\*/}.*\.java$` otherwise; the Path's toString is then matched against that pattern.

If you use other `FileSystem` implementation (like [JimFs](https://github.com/google/jimfs), [memoryfilesystem](https://github.com/marschall/memoryfilesystem) or [TrueVFS](https://truevfs.java.net/)), the last part is important because it simply means that while the `PathMatcher` is generated by a `FileSystem`, it actually accept any `Path` and will not yield an exception for path not produced by the `FileSystem`.